# update WPF DataGrid content after changes in Database

Tags: c#, wpf

I make an application by C# and WPF technology.

I have a method to update my Datagrid content:

```
dgContact.ItemsSource = db.ContactRepository.GetAllContact();
```

after every add or update, I call this method.
if I add a record, a new record shown in my grid.
but if I update a record, changes not be displayed in my grid (changed in DB).

how I can update Datagrid content by last data in DB?

thanks

Comment: the db.ContactRepository.GetAllContact() method what structure returns? A generic List? An ObservableCollection?

Comment: @Marlonchosky Generic List. no problem in getting data for the first time. just in the update!

Comment: I answered your question. Like you'll see, your problem depends in what structure you are returning in your method.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the type of structure that your method returns.

If your method returns a non-ObservableCollection, what you can do is before setting DataGrid.ItemsSource to your method, set DataGrid1.ItemsSource = null; In this way, you are telling the WPF system that there was a change and that your DataGrid will be updated, like this:

```
private void Update_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    this.DataGrid1.ItemsSource = null;
    this.DataGrid1.ItemsSource = db.ContactRepository.GetAllContact();
}
```

On the other hand, if your method returns an [ObservableCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1?view=netframework-4.8), just set the ItemsSource property the way you did it before, and the WPF system will detect the change.

Check [this](https://github.com/marlonedu/WpfTests/tree/master/WpfApp11) project so you could verify it.

Answer (score 0):

You can Bind the DataDrid ItemSource to ObservableCollection, try to do your changes with the database then update the ObservableCollection and it notifies when a change has been made.